# Delete file if pipe closes before completion

Tags: javascript, node.js, pipe

I have written a simple Node.js script which saves remote files to a cache using the following code:

```
// Pipe from Imgur to cache
request('http://i.imgur.com/' + file).pipe(fs.createWriteStream('cache/' + file));
```

If the user closes the browser tab or navigates out before file has been downloaded fully, a damaged file is left. How can I either delete incomplete transfers, have them persist after the window is closed, or prevent saving till all data is downloaded?

Comment: Is there no 'close' or 'error' event, dispatched?

Comment: According to [the docs](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_readable_pipe_destination_options) there is only the 'end' event, which does not distinguish between success and failure.

Comment: One alternative would be to check the size of the file before the download and after the `end` event.

Answer (score 0):

fancy this code:

```
var fetchData = request(url);

var data ='';  

fetchData.on("data",function(d){
data+=d;
});

fetchData.on("end",function(){       
    fs.writeFile('cache/' +file,data,function(err){
        if(err)console.log(err);
    })

});
```

this downloads the file even if the user exits..